# Cannot connect to Hololens 2 device portal via WiFi

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I cannot connect to the device portal, I see this error:

The connection for this site is not secure10.110.8.181 sent an invalid response.
Try running network diagnostics with Get Help.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I can build and run programs with visual studio, but I cannot acces the device portal

I allowed the browser to access Hololens 2's IP.

Comment: Try connecting to  `https://10.110.8.181` and NOT `http://10.110.8.181` but you would have to have an SSL installed on that server to get an encrypted connection.

Answer (score 0):

About how to connect to the device portal, you can access https://<YOUR_HOLOLENS_IP_ADDRESS> via a web browser on your PC. Please refer to this tutorial for details [Using the Windows Device Portal - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-windows-device-portal)